# Gateway MX6455 screen flickers turns a reddish hue

Tags: laptop

My laptop screen started flickering and turns a reddish hue almost as soon as I turn it on.  It flickers so much I have to hard power down cause I can't see the icons.  I hooked it up to my desktop monitor and everything is fine. Is this an inverter issue or LCD issue?

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like a loose flex connector on the edge of the display and *probably* not the inverter. You might be able to confirm this by watching the screen as you gently pinch/squeeze the bezel area around it - you might find one point where pressure 'cures' the problem until you let go.

If you do find a 'fix spot' then you have to decide whether you want to risk opening up the laptop and trying to secure down the connector - sometimes just a strip of adhesive tape will do, but it can be a 'kill or cure' moment if you disturb the connector and make things worse.

If the display panel is not fixable then the next alternative is a replacement - there's often a good selection of suppliers on your favourite auction site, but do check part numbers and perhaps speak to them to ensure you get the right panel, and if you're not keen to open up your laptop, seek out a local repair centre anyway.

Comment: Great! Thanks for the info. Will repost with results.